# What's the meaning of ぴっと。

Tags: meaning

Here is the sentence :

> 1年たったらここんとこを**ピッと**おせばレーダーに反応がでるとおもうわ!

I didn't find any information about ぴっと in the dictionaries I searched in...

Comment: I think it's a sound effect (beep) of a button press but I'm not sure

Comment: @Flaw そうそう、こんな音 -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3DrK8dK8VA Flawさん回答して～ :D

Comment: @Alox It's 「ピッ」 not 「ぴっと」 though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a sound effect (beep) of a button press. This is a [sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3DrK8dK8VA) from youtube.